# Best Approach to handle Duplicate columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, duplicates, ssms

I have a table with a few columns, and a certain column, say 'Mould_Number' has duplicate entries.
By duplicate, i mean that only the Mould_Number for certain rows are same, however the other column values can/maynot be so.
what is the best approach to handle such duplicate data, if i want to say in SQL Database, and not Migrate to No-SQL? 
For instance, in the image, SRP-AS-64 has multiple entries, some of which are entirely duplicates, and the others have different attributes.
I am developing an ERP software, and this table currently has about 5000 rows.
What is the best way to handle this kind of data?

[image]

Comment: Add sample data and eexpected output

Comment: So Mould_Number Is Your Product.But It is not duplicated If you See The Part No Of SRP-AS-64 is Diff so still if you think is Duplicate Then I can give you the Solution

Comment: It is a duplicate. This problem occured when the employees at the Firm Made excel sheets for this data. It is irrelevant what part_No i use, as long as the Dimension is unique.

Comment: What is the query that generated this output?  Is this how your application is saving the data?  If so, you will need to read up on [Normalisation](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) and change how you are holding your application data to be more sensible.

Comment: this was just a select * on the table.
I found the query which helped me view only unique Mould_No values on the data, but I cannot delete the Duplicate Data. 
My point being, The reason why Mould_No has more than one value, supposedly unique, is because they have "Complex Moulds" i.e. 5-6 moulds that make up a Unique mould!  But they have entered that data as separate values in the Excel sheet.
Hence the duplication. :/ 
Sorry for the Ambiguity!